# Change the edit link image in oracle apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex

I created an application with oracle apex, and I want to create an interactive report. So created a page by following the wizard. In one of the steps, it asked me to choose an image for the edit link, as shown in the picture below[image: edit link].

My Problem is that, now, I would like to change the image of this edit link, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit the IR's attributes, under Link Column you will see something like this:

[image]

Or if using the newer Page Designer you would see this:
[image]

Change the name of the image file (`e2.gif` here) to the one you want.

If you don't know the name of the one you want, create another page temporarily and use the wizard to get the one you want, then have a look to see what the filename is.

Comment: Could you please show me how to find this page? I tried but couldn't find this page.

Comment: Sorry, I forget not everyone uses the old-style interface.  See updated answer for Page Designer equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i waht!